# Work done by battery

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, work, capacitance, inductance

In charging a capacitor to a charge $Q$

[image]

Is there an equivalent to this in setting up current through an inductive circuit?

Energy stored in inductor $= 1/2Li^2$

What would be the work done in setting up the current $i$ in the inductor?

(I'm in high school, I have trouble deriving the work done for this one. For the capacitor, since the final voltage across it would be the emf of the battery, I can understand the expression for work done by the battery (as shown in the above image) but for inductor it is a little tricky since its voltage is given by $L*(di/dt)$.)

Comment: Hi! Please use MathJax to format equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an inductive circuit, the current never stops flowing. It tends towards a maximum value (assuming some amount of resistance, for the circuit to heat up.)

If E is the emf of the battery, L is the inductance, and R is the resistance,
the battery is constantly doing work even once the terminal current $\frac{E}{R}$ is achieved, and heat is being dissipated in the resistance.

If you work out the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}Eidt = \int_0^\infty\frac{E^2}{R}(1-e^{-Rt/L})$$ it blows up to infinity

In the case of the capacitive circuit, the battery stops doing work once the capacitor is charged, hence we get a finite expression.

Comment: Thanks! This question was asked back in 1999 in an entrance test and there was no credible source for answers, the ones on the internet being either Li^2 or 1/2Li^2.

Comment: *"It tends towards a maximum value"* Or, in the case of a constant-current source, stays constant.